# Where to host a python chat server?

Tags: python, server, xmpp, host

I wrote a python app that manage gcm messaging for an android chat app, where could I host this app to be able to work 24/7, **it's not a web app**, Is it safe and reliable to use PythonAnywhere consoles?

Comment: if it's a server that accepts incoming messages etc, then you should host it as a webapp. If you are insistent on running it as a script, the PythonAnywhere consoles do restart say every other week for maintenance etc. check out pythonanywhere long running tasks as a solution to that https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/LongRunningTasks

Comment: That will make me change the app, I guess using a virtual linux server is the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here: I wouldn't recommend our consoles as a place to run an XMPP server -- they're meant more for exploratory programming.  AWS (like Adam Barnes suggests) or a VPS somewhere like Digital Ocean would probably be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard anything bad about PythonAnywhere, and their [testimonials](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/about/testimonials/) page looks fairly reasonable, if devoid of megahuge company names.

If you're not convinced, try [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).  The company I currently work for hosts its websites there, as do thousands of others.

Comment: I edited my question, is it reliable to use PythonAnywhere consoles?

Comment: Edited my answer :D